# Multiple R installations... lost overview

Tags: python, r, conda

I am running Ubuntu 14 and I am using R and R studio. I think the installation is at:

```
/usr/bin/R
```

Recently, I wanted to use the [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) to also run R in this kind of notebook in the browser.

I therefore installed miniconda, anaconda, and the irkernel packages.

However, I am now having the problem that I lost my base r installation:

```
which R
 /home/user/miniconda2/bin/R
```

This seems to be related to another problem that recently has started to occur when installing R packages on the command line:

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5
```

Moreover, it also seems that Rstudio comes with its own version of R:

```
/home/user/software/rstudio-0.98.1103/R
```

That means, there are at least 3 different R versions. Well, to be honest. I totally lost my overview. The same thing applies for python, which I installed with apt-get and conda.

Could anyone please help me to clean up that mess?

Answer (score 0):

most probably tcl libraries will be present in your `/home/user/miniconda2/lib` folder. so set your env variables in your ~/.bashrc file.

`export TCL_LIBRARY="/home/palashkulshreshtha/Documents/anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5"
export TK_LIBRARY="/home/palashkulshreshtha/Documents/anaconda3/lib/tk8.5"`

make sure your tcl8.5 and tk8.5 directories are present.
This solved the problem for me as then conda will look into above directories for init.tcl and other requirements.